# Retrieving many different kinds of models from the database at the same time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have set up a number of different models in my ruby on rails blog project. Currently the different model types are articles, quick tips, quotes and definitions. I've created a page where I would like to display all of these in a single flow ordered by creation time.

**The question**: What is a smart/efficient way to retrieve a specific number of items, chosen among all of the content types, ordered by creation date.

Hopefully illustrative pseudo code:

```
Db.load([:Tip, :Quote, :Article, :Definition]).order_by(:created_at).limit(10)
```

The best solution I've come up with myself so far is to load 10 items of every category, sort them and pick the latest 10 of the sorted list. :P

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the schema for your tables.

Comment: You could create a VIEW in SQL ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656864/sql-create-view-from-multiple-tables ) and then query this view to get all latest records.

Comment: MrYoshiji, your answer depends on there being shared ids or something that one can make joins on, however these tables have nothing in common at all. As such I don't want to combine anything into compound rows I just want to retrieve data from several tables at once, sorted by creation date, _efficiently_.

Comment: André Dion, while I sympathize with your desire to have all the facts, I am quite certain the specifics of each table are uninteresting for the question at hand as the problem should be quite generic. Just assume the tables are completely unrelated, contain different fields and shares no information. If you still think seeing the full schema would be helpful, then I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to do what I want is to make a superclass, say Post, and have all other content types inherit from this Model. This will create a Single Table Inheritance scheme where all of the subclasses attributes are kept in the "posts" table together with a "type" attribute which facillitates differentiating between the content types. I should still be able to use all content types normally, but also get a Posts model where I can query and sort all content types at the same time.

[More information about the technique can be found here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just combine them.

```
(Tip.all + Quote.all + Article.all + Definition.all).order_by(:created_at).limit(10)
```

Or

```
tips = Tips.all.limit(10)
quotes = Quotes.all.limit(10)
(tips + quotes).order_by(:created_at).limit(10)
```

Get the idea?

[Possibly useful similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498525/merging-two-arrays-of-different-objects-in-rails)

Comment: I got really excited by this answer since it seemed an elegant solution, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. The problem is that the concatenation of the arrays doesn't produce a new ActiveRecord Relation but an ordinary Ruby Array - which doesn't have order_by or limit methods.

The link you provided was helpful but the answer there loads the objects into an array and then sorts it (as opposed to having it sorted directly in the retrieval from the database). Essentially, it gives the same solution as the one I described at the bottom of my question... but perhaps there is no better solution?

Comment: Yeah. That's my bad. I didn't test it. The 2nd answer could be manually sorted and then limited.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Tip, Quote, Article, Definition].map{|model_name| model_name.order(:created_at).first(10)}
```

Comment: So this code essentialy makes an array of arrays where each sub-array contains 10 items of a given type sorted by creation date. This is not what I was asking for. I wanted a single array of objects of all kinds that are sorted by creation time and, if possible, without loading more than 10 objects at all. This answer loads 40 objects from the database when there are enough objects in each category.

Comment: Oh i got it wrongly. Why not sql query 'select column_name from tips union select column_name from quotes union select column_name from articles union select column_name from definitions order by created_at;'  Then do an connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection; ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).

Comment: That's a good idea, however the different tables doesn't have the same number of fields - which is required for a union. Another, perhaps comparatively small, caveat is that the connection returns hashes instead of models.